# Mysql Inner join with concat_ws

Tags: mysql, concat-ws

I have 2 table.

**first table**

```
 | idgroup | namegroup
```

**second table**

```
 | idrequest | col1 | col2 | N1 | N2 | date_extract  |
```

I want to join the tables with `concat_ws`

```
    SELECT
    tb1.*,tb2.*,
    CONCAT_WS("_",tb2.N1, tb2.N2) AS GR,
    FROM
    table2 tb2
    INNER JOIN table1 tb1 ON tb1.namegroup= tb2.GR
    WHERE
    tb2.date_extract = "2015-02-13"
```

Is it possible? then how?

Comment: What happens when you execute this query? Do you see errors?

Comment: [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'tb2.GR' in 'on clause'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am giving a blind try. Nothing changed much except a date() conversion to `tb2.date_extract`-taking the date value if `date_extract` is of type `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME`.

```
SELECT
    tb1.*,tb2.*,
    CONCAT_WS("_",tb2.`N1`, tb2.`N2`) AS `GR`,
    FROM
    table2 tb2
    INNER JOIN table1 tb1 ON tb1.`namegroup`= tb2.GR
    WHERE
    date(tb2.`date_extract`) = "2015-02-13"
```

If this is not your problem, then please post the error message with the question.

UPDATE: You can simply use `GR` instead of `tbl2.GR` need to use the namespace for the result

```
SELECT
    tb1.*, tb2.*, CONCAT_WS("_",tb2.`N1`, tb2.`N2`) AS `GR`,
    FROM table2 tb2
    INNER JOIN table1 tb1 ON tb1.`namegroup`= `GR`
WHERE
    date(tb2.`date_extract`) = "2015-02-13"
```

-now let me know how it goes?

Comment: [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'tb2.GR' in 'on clause'

Comment: Okay. The problem is with your JOIN(grouping columns for JOIN condition)

Comment: usermesam23 have you the solution sql?

Comment: Please show us the CREATE TABLEs you are dealing with !

Comment: Work if i use "LEFT OUTER JOIN"

Thank very much to all